# How to ignore problems in VS Code

Tags: javascript, flask, visual-studio-code

When VS Code detects a problem in the code and I know it is not a problem for me, how do I make the pesky problem messages, red highlighting of the file, and red underlining of the problem areas go away?

For example, I am passing in data from my Flask server through a template:

```
    <script>
        var dataFromFlask = {{ data_from_flask }};
    </script>
```

But VS Code doesn't like that and gives me these problems:
Property assignment expected.
Declaration or statement expected.

I have no extensions installed.

Comment: Are you using an extension for the language you are using? is it set to use said extension on the correct file types?

Comment: You most likely need to change your `<script>` tag type.. eg.  `type="text/flask"` or something like that.

Comment: Adding `type="text/flask"` removed the problems.

Comment: But then the code doesn't work as intended. dataFromFlask is undefined.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60175608/visual-studio-code-and-jinja-templates